# django rest framework: : Passing raw query

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Is it possible to perform raw queries in django rest framework like django. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes you should be able to, since you can customize the queryset that backs your view, e.g.

```
class MyModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    # The usual stuff here
    model = MyModel

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = MyModel.objects.raw('... your SQL here...')
        serializer = MyModelSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

`Manager.raw()` returns `RawQuerySet` which is a `QuerySet`, so you can see how it all fits

Comment: But when i am join queries it displaying only one table data. Is it possible. is there another to fetch data join queries?

Comment: somechow I know your question is from 2014, but another person has the same doubt, this can help: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/sql/

Comment: somehow when I define list as describe, DRF still looking for get_queryset() method which require an ordinary model based QuerySet instead of RawQuerySet.