# Using raw SQL in django-rest framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django 1.8 with a Postgres 9.4 back-end with tables and materialized views.

I have an 80GB table called `spending` with spending items, each with an organisation code and a region code:

```
class Prescription(models.Model):
  region = models.ForeignKey(Region)
  organisation = models.ForeignKey(Organisation)
  month = models.DateField()
  amount = models.FloatField()
```

I also have a materialized view for `spending_by_region`, generated from the `spending` table:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW spending_by_region AS 
      SELECT region, month, SUM(amount) AS amount 
      FROM spending
      GROUP BY month, region_id
```

(I'm using the materialized views because the data is very large and static, effectively a data warehouse.)

Some of my Django views use the materialized views, e.g. my view for each region. In these cases I use raw SQL to run `select * from spending_by_region where region=123`, because of course Django's ORM doesn't know about materialized views.

Now I want to start implementing an API for my application. I have heard good things about django-rest-framework, but will it be possible to use raw SQL queries to get the data before serializing it?

For example, if I want an API method called `/spending_by_region/123`, will it be possible to run the same query as above?

I found [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26016364/194000), but it's still tied to a Model field, rather than being purely raw SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django-Rest-Framework works at the top of a Django Application, You can set a custom manager to the models you want and execute raw queries, or simply use the `.raw()` method from Django's ORM. It's like any other Django application, but you gain the views and serializers to respond JSON objects.

Comment: thanks - I won't even actually be using the `.raw()` method, I'll be executing custom SQL directly and getting a cursor back - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly can I then pass the cursor to django-rest-framework somehow?

Comment: Yes, I guess you execute it in a view, with DRF, you have view extending from [APIView](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/) and there you can define methods (usually POST), and there execute any Python/Django valid code, and return it as JSON with [Response](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/responses/#response) method.